# How to reduce the noise from a kitchen to a bedroom?

Tags: noise, bedroom, noise-reduction

What are some ways that I can use to reduce the noise from   the same apartment of a bedroom? The room is one door and wall separated from a shared kitchen, which is sometimes busy and noisy. I'd like to concentrate on study and sleep. I now play white noise from my laptop to drown the noise. The least expensive way the better, and I don't own the place and may only make minimal change and have more control of the room than the kitchen,  I may or may not be able to ask the owner to make some change, but I'd like to hear all possible  options. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a door on this wall?

Comment: yes..................

Comment: First place to start is the door. Drape with heavy blankets. Figure a way to easily deploy and remove

Comment: add rugs, both to the kitchen and your room. A folding privacy screen with a blanket on it in front of the loud wall will also help greatly.

Comment: @dandavis can you show me some pictures?